# How to display the Timer Countdown on the Screen

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

//A simple countdown timer

```
var myTimer : float = 5.0;

function Update () {
 if(myTimer > 0){
  myTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
 }
 if(myTimer <= 0){
  Debug.Log("GAME OVER");
 }
}
```

This is a countdowntimer script I just want it to show it up on the screen while it counts down .

Comment: I don't think you can do `var myTimer : float` in JavaScript. And what triggers your `Update` function?

Comment: @putvande `Update` is one of the most important function in Unity game engine and is called on every frame.

Answer (score 3):

Put it OnGUI() such as

```
function OnGUI () {
    GUI.Label (Rect (10,10,150,100), myTimer.ToString());
}
```

Comment: myTimer is a float, not a string!

Comment: How can I made it to a string?

Comment: Oh yes, add .ToString()

Answer (score 2):

You probably also want to have this outside the Update() method, and have the logic run only when it's necessary. This can be done by using the InvokeRepeating method like this (C#):

```cs
float myTimer = 5.0f;

void Start() {
    InvokeRepeating( "DecreaseTime", 1, 1 ); // Called every second
}

void DecreaseTime() {
    myTimer--;
}

void onGUI() {
    GUI.Label(new Rect(10,10,400,90), "myTimer = " + myTimer );
}
```